# facebook connect for android returns a blank login screen?

Tags: android, facebook

i am trying to use the old facebook connect authentication to authenticate my android client to get the necessary session id's and other credentials thats needed to start using the web service of facebook.

the issue i am having is that when my android application launces and tries to load the login page for facebook, that very same login page is blank and it only displays the the facebook logo as the title of the screen.

No login fields or buttons are visible leaving me nowhere to login and authenticate a user.

i have tried two API's one is facebook connect api for android http://code.google.com/p/fbconnect-android/  and the other one is the official android facebook sdk that is recommended to be used instead of the previous one i have just mentioned https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/ .

please see the image below of how it looks like on my app.

[image]

Here is code that uses the latest android sdk facebook:

```
/**
 * Authenticate facebook network
 */
private void authenticateFacebook() {
    // TODO: move this away from this activty class into some kind of
    // helper/wrapper class
    Log.d(TAG, "Clicked on the facebook");

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook(OAUTH_KEY_FACEBOOK_API);

    facebook.authorize(this, new AuthorizeListener());
}

class AuthorizeListener implements DialogListener{

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "finished authorizing facebook user");

    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And a simple example of how to use it: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

My code is more or less identical to the above example.

edit: i did not catch what logcat was inputing in my first attempted at my code above but their was no exceptions or warnings thrown at the time. just a blank page.

i then tried it again and diddnt touch my code and what happens now is that a loading dialogue view pops up and stays their for a few minutes until the facebook windows disapears and the logcat outputs the error below:

> 11-18 17:26:19.913:
>   DEBUG/Facebook-WebView(783): Webview
>   loading URL:
>   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?type=user_agent&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&display=touch&client_id=e???????????????????
>   11-18 17:27:01.756:
>   DEBUG/Facebook-authorize(783): Login
>   failed:
>   com.kc.unity.agent.util.oauth.facebook.DialogError:
>   The connection to the server was
>   unsuccessful. 11-18 17:27:01.783:
>   DEBUG/Facebook-WebView(783): Webview
>   loading URL:
>   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?type=user_agent&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&display=touch&client_id=???????????????

please note that the client id i have amended for obvious reasons but the rest of the logcat is untouched

Comment: Can a web browser on the same phone visit http://www.facebook.com, and does your app have INTERNET privilege?

Comment: @sotapanna See my edits.  logcat diddnt return any exceptions the first time i tried it.

@yuliy, yes my app has internet privilege and can also browse facebook.com fine.

Comment: Ok i just tried it now and the login screen seems to work. Not quite their yet as when i login to facebook, the webpage goes straight to the facebook main page instead of bringing up a new web page that asks me if i want to allow my application to authenticate and use details from my facebook account

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions please? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, the cause of this is because you have a Facebook app installed on your phone.

and ...

After lot of effort I solved that error. It very simple. This is error will appear above `2.2` android version. May be it's cause of hash key error.

**Steps to solve this issue**

Open your facebook library (`com.facebook.android`) which is added as library
Open `FaceBook.java` class
In that we will found `private static final int DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 32665`. You should change to `DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE` to -1
Now save it and clean and build both library and your application
Note :

*this blank screen appear only for latest versions only.*

Comment: Didn't work for me either Galaxy IIIs, Android 4.0.4, has anybody another suggestion, this is driving me crazy?

Answer (score 1):

If anybody experience this problem, you might have enabled the sandbox mode during creating this application in facebook developer site.Go disable it then it works fine.