# facebook api on android: blank screen instead of auth

Tags: android, facebook

I've searched for the past 3 hours for answers regarding this problem, and similar questions did not help, so I'm finally asking the question:

I'm trying to use Facebook's SDK for Android, and I'm getting a "blank" screen (there's a frame around it, but where you'd expect the authorization details I'm instead getting white space):

[image: A blank screen.]

Clicking "Log In" gives the same page, only the title is now "Error" with a vague message:

[image: An error screen.]

- I've checked that the hash key is right. I've changed the hash key to something absurd like "asdf" and the log indeed says that the application is using `[some key]` and isn't matching. So I replaced "asdf" with `[some key]` and that error went away. (Additionally, the page above doesn't even show up in the case of incorrect hash keys, it just ends the auth process immediately.)
- I've checked that date and time settings are correct, so at least SSL isn't breaking with respect to that. I don't see any related errors or warnings in logcat, either.
- I did find [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216147/facebook-connect-for-android-returns-a-blank-login-screen) (no real answers) and the linked [solution](http://myunixworld.blogspot.com/2010/11/android-facebook-sdk-issue-fix-for.html?showComment=1294381258058_AIe9_BGDXca377UlwHOlEr_p3SJo12zdJuK42VkyQyYl2Gqsfx9VfB3w5QY1uqNULDAG_frHqG1hhcgBM1zRquKKCw9_dUIT9Zi38PWDCUdDYqSExi6CNZlNfp4TS4132UXnfwoLaNZ7uF7Tw-kvVMMGzG0QWdZiqE484x-7MLu9lvTNgtRbyNfcPdnh8mEWl7COb_xARXlkG0JcrylLGxt0X2xG62H_8QEwdxmbWA0-Dy1UkB5dmArXYRACe2iIibXU6vy6p-1kR2NcSHRpb0UiPujnTI92m_0KKIEZmB6WeQ5zVrJy9FL8saBsFv_bFoZ8Aq2nM9QyhgqYBIwnjamjTsB85YyPgrw0gMNnaBf7bA_STnhZA0PVUziGp3ghwvamKBoiEnh6oCGlptQAXwLKK1IDQS44V6_ZWim7vtuDSXu5Qj-SOHNuWdU7ttqwAhlwWIPAYIIlrXjHX7fSnUHv98ZOjSVFne93h8lnHhwpTjLMB7Wc-SI#c5442685186348999639) but that seems outdated. (And it doesn't work.)

I'm following the FB tutorial at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#enablesso word for word, and at this point I have no idea how to debug this with no errors or warnings in the log. Has anybody else seen this bug before?

(I'm using Android API 15 with the latest clone of the github for the FB API.)

Comment: I've the same kind of issue. I just upgraded the new FB SDK and this is what happens to me...

Comment: I'm also facing the same.. since today morning.. it was working fine yesterday with the same code..

Comment: Me too Vishal but I tought it was a problem of the new SDK because today I just upgraded. Anyway I downgraded and the problem is still here.

Comment: You first check weather in your device is there a internet connected. Normally if device has no internet connection then it give same type of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue using Titanium mobile development on andorid and both using a webview or using SSO give the same result.

Edit: A bug has been filed so please sign up to it as well:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/385350798163367?browse=search_4f8ed4596fd900857644164

Comment: Yeah. I have been refreshing like crazy hoping that they (FB staff) would accept the bug report. And I hope they are frantically trying to fix it, even if they refuse to accept the bug report and acknowledge the problem.... And I all this time, I was thinking I must have messed up the code somewhere. :-(

Comment: @user584859 this link / bug does not exist anymore. Clicking the link will get you to the bug listing page.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I've tried multiple different apps that require a Facebook login, and all of those had the same problem. Seems like it may be a bug on Facebook.

Comment: Hm, similarly I removed Foursquare's permission to my account, logged out of Foursquare mobile (Android), and tried again. Indeed foursquare is hitting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

They recognized the problem and started to investigate:

[Click](https://developers.facebook.com/live_status/)

Answer (score -1):

After lot of effort I solved that error. It very simple. This is error will appear above 2.2 android version. May be it's cause of hash key error.

**Steps to solve this issue**

1. Open your facebook library  ( com.facebook.android) which is added as library
2. Open FaceBook.java class
3. In that we will found private static final int DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 32665. You should change to **DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE to -1**
4. Now save it and clean and build both library and your application

**Note** :

this blank screen appear only for latest versions only .