# Android Facebook SDK valid redirect url

Tags: android, facebook, api, authentication, redirect

I tried to integrate facebook in my android application. The only thing I need to know is the facebook-id of the user of the app (used in the local facebook app).

So I followed the official tutorial to try it out, and everything seems to work fine, BUT:

if I try to authenticate in the code via:

```
    facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
```

The facebook screen with the name of my facebook app is displayed, with the two button "Cancel" and "Login", but no content.

If I click login, I get the following error:

```
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: Requires valid redirect URL.
```

I read a few other threads that suggested turning off "Enhanced Auth Dialog" in the app settings on facebook, but this didn't change anything.

My debug hash is the right one, cause I already got an error for this an fixed it, so this is not the problem.

Searched for hours now, and found no solution.

Has anyone a hint of what to do to fix this?

**EDIT**

It's the same problem as here:
[Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202245/facebook-api-on-android-blank-screen-instead-of-auth)

Sorry for the double..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with the facebook android SSO.

Take a look at the [platform status](http://developers.facebook.com/live_status/):

> We are working on a fix for the Android SSO errors. Please subscribe
>   to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/385350798163367 for updates
>   with this issue.

Comment: thanks, I searched reason whole day! You saved my tomorrow day!