# Facebook Like Button click showing blank page and getting dismissed automatically

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am using Facebook SDK 4.8.0 and LikeView provided by Facebook SDK
I am getting blank page when I am clicking on Like button

[image: Facebook blank image when click on LIKE button]

[image: Facebook LikeView Button]

in XML

```
      <com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
        android:id="@+id/likeView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

in ManiFest

```
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
        android:value="@string/app_name" />
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
       android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <provider                          android:authorities="com.facebook.app.
FacebookContentProviderXXXXXXXX"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|
            screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

In Java

```
      likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.likeView);
         likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);
             likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(
             LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
        likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
            "https://www.facebook.com/AndroidOfficial/",
            LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
        likeView.setOnClickListener(
             new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Facebook like");
        }
    });
    likeView.setOnErrorListener(new LikeView.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Facebook error :- " + error.getMessage());
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Please help me with the issue as I developed the same way instructed on Facebook developer

Comment: any error message?

Comment: no error message printed.

Comment: Have uyou accomplished such functionality with any of your android app having facebook sdk 4.8.0 or newer?

Comment: never implemented like button, sorry. Maybe something like this could help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202245/facebook-api-on-android-blank-screen-instead-of-auth

Comment: Thanks @firegloves.
I got how the problem came. You need to keep app as Private till you are not submitting it for Review. But now I am facing antoher problem in whick LikeView text is not getting changed,